# Decrementing using existing field in sqlite3 with codeigniter

Tags: sqlite, codeigniter

```
foreach($item_ids AS $i => $v) {
            $q = $quantity[$i];
            if($v!='' && $v>0) {
                    $update_stock[] = array(
                          'p_id' => $v ,
                          'quantity' => 'quantity'-$q
                       );   



            }
        }
```

$updated = $this->sales_model->update_stock($update_stock);

I am facing problem with `'quantity' => 'quantity'-$q`

Tell me whats wrong with the code. I want to decrement column quantity by $q.

Comment: You're trying to substract `$q` from a string :)

Comment: @lesssugar I want that value must be decremented by $q . If column quantity has value 10 and $q is 2 then column must be updated to 10-2=8. I tried without quotes:`'quantity' => quantity-intval($q)` but it gives error:-Use of undefined constant quantity - assumed 'quantity'.

Comment: @lesssugar I got one solution `$this->db->set('field', 'field+2', FALSE);` but I want this with update_batch